# How can I collapse a nested ul list?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an ul list, that toggles if I click on an item that has other items inside:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the script:

```
$('li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ullist = $(this).parent().children('ul:first');
    ullist.slideToggle();
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPnnM/)

I would like that on pageload all "folders" are closed.

I tried to do it like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var ullist = $('li a').parent().children('ul:first');
    ullist.hide();
    $('li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ullist = $(this).parent().children('ul:first');
        ullist.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

but then only the main "folder" is closed and when I click on it, all the other folders are open.

Comment: I have the result! Need to change `var ullist = $('li a').parent().children('ul:first');` into `var ullist = $('li a').parent().children('ul');`

Comment: But the problem with my solution, all folders and content is flushing for one second before hiding. Is this possible to prevent?

Comment: If your answer is solved, answer your own question and mark it as Solved. Regarding your last comment, if you want them to prevent "flushing" for one second before hiding, why not to set the CSS property for those `ul` by default as hidden? This way, by default they will be hidden, and will still have the functionality you wrote.

Comment: @Unapedra Good idea! Unfortunately I cannot find a "solved" button

Comment: Just hit the 'tick' toggle (✓) under your own answer votes (you have to wait 4 hours, I think, so you can mark as solved your own answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collapse all lists you can use `$('ul ul').hide()` on document ready:

Answer (score 0):

I have the result! Need to change var `ullist = $('li a').parent().children('ul:first');` into `var ullist = $('li a').parent().children('ul');`